# in C# when I convert excel to text with the help of excel saveAs method then extra double quotes come with string(text) data

Tags: c#, reporting-services

in C# when I convert excel to text with the help of excel saveAs method then extra double quotes come with string(text) data, for this

Problem after did google, we found one solution to use .prn(printer file) then issue resolved but it's printer file so data cut.full data not coming in printer file. I'm not found the proper solution so that.

what is the best approach to get full data without double quotes?

Thanks,

Kapil

Comment: Are you converting to something similar to .csv?

Answer (score 0):

I think your converting .csv file into text file. As .csv file contains commas at last of each line, you have to remove them.

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName,File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName).Replace(",", "\t"));

This will remove last commas in each row.